# label the graph for r radar graph

Tags: r, radar-chart

```
#R-radar map for sub-categories price-elasticity:  
#Make data frame  
SUB_CAT <- c("PRETZEL","PIZZA","ADULT CEREAL", "FAMILY CEREAL", "MOUTHWASH", "MOUTHWASH(ANTISEPTIC)", "KIDS CEREAL") 
Max <- c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5) 
Min <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
Price_elasticity <- c(1.512, 1.392, 0.3675, 0.2229, 1.2, 0.4676, 2.317) 
PE<- data.frame(SUB_CAT,Max, Min, Price_elasticity)  

#Make radar chart  
M<-PE %>%  
  pivot_longer(cols = -SUB_CAT) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = SUB_CAT, values_from = value) %>%  
  column_to_rownames("name")  

radarchart( M  , axistype=0.5 ,   
            #custom polygon  
            pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5), plwd=5 ,            
            #custom the grid  
            cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,3,0.7), cglwd=0.8,        
            #custom labels  
            vlcex=0.5)
```

I made this radar graph, but for some reason, the numbers for the grid is not showing up.

I keep getting this: 
[image: the graph I get]

but I want this: 
[image: this is what I want]

I had the same code for both, I think but when I try it again my labels are just gone, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The help of `radarchart ` says `axistype`: The type of axes, specified by any of 0:5. 0 means no axis label. 1 means center axis label only. 2 means around-the-chart label only. 3 means both center and around-the-chart (peripheral) labels. 4 is *.** format of 1, 5 is *.** format of 3. Default is 0. But you are specifying 0.5 which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `axistype=1` giving me the numbers for the grid like

```
library(fmsb)
library(tidyverse)

#R-radar map for sub-categories price-elasticity:  
#Make data frame  
SUB_CAT <- c("PRETZEL","PIZZA","ADULT CEREAL", "FAMILY CEREAL", "MOUTHWASH", "MOUTHWASH(ANTISEPTIC)", "KIDS CEREAL") 
Max <- c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5) 
Min <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
Price_elasticity <- c(1.512, 1.392, 0.3675, 0.2229, 1.2, 0.4676, 2.317) 
PE<- data.frame(SUB_CAT,Max, Min, Price_elasticity)  

#Make radar chart  
M<-PE %>%  
  pivot_longer(cols = -SUB_CAT) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = SUB_CAT, values_from = value) %>%  
  column_to_rownames("name")  

radarchart(M, axistype=1,   
            #custom polygon  
            pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5), plwd=2,            
            #custom the grid  
            cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,3,0.5), cglwd=0.8,        
            #custom labels  
            vlcex=0.5)
```

[image]